# SQL - Order by Then Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to show items with the cheapest price, then group by item alphabetically.

I have a picture below to best describes what I am looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subquery`:

```
select * 
from table t
where price = (select min(price) from table where Item = t.Item)
order by Item;
```

However, be careful while same item has two same *min* price

**EDIT:**

You can change the `where` clause and use *limit* clause

```
select * 
from table t
where id = (select id
            from table 
            where Item = t.Item
            order by price desc
            LIMIT 1)
order by Item;
```

Comment: Hi, your query works as expected however I see what you mean by same min price, is there anyway it could retrun 1 row for the same min price? do I have to group the result by item again? please help ...also it would be nice to shoose for myself which shop should be returned for the same price min that returns more than 1 row (for the same price)

Comment: @user3560827... You can use `LIMIT` inside subquery check edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining to a subquery which finds the lowest price record for each item:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Item, MIN(Price) AS min_price
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Item
) t2
    ON t1.Item = t2.Item AND
       t1.Price = t2.min_price
ORDER BY
    t1.Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.price = (select min(t2.price) from t t2 where t2.item = t.item)
order by t.item;
```

For performance, you want an index on `(item, price)`.

Note:  This will return multiple rows for each item, if they all have the same minimum price.  If you want to guarantee one row, then you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.item = t.item
              order by t2.price desc
              limit 1
             )
order by t.item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

SELECT * FROM `(table name)` GROUP BY item,price,model,color,shop ORDER BY item,price,model,color,shop ASC